# Moving files begins fast then slows down dramatically at the end

Tags: windows-8.1, file-transfer

Moving files begins fast then slows down dramatically at the end.
Any idea why?

[image: See here]

Answer (score 4):

- If you're moving file from a fast drive (e.g. your internal SSD) to a slower drive (e.g. a USB stick), Windows (or other modern OS) usually reads as much data as possible into memory buffer. So the fast speed you're seeing at the beginning is just your faster drive's transfer speed to RAM (which is almost infinitely fast), while the slower one in the end is the "real" speed.
- If there are both large and small files in the folder being moved/copied, small file is processed slower than large ones due to mechanical/engineering limits.

EDIT: I didn't see your image first... My apologies. Then the first bullet may continue to apply, but the second one not.